# Git does not ignore files in my project

Tags: git, gitignore

I am still struggling with Git. I have git local repos. It look like below:

```
project
  - .git
     - .gitignore
  - child [directory]
  - some files
```

.gitignore:

```
target/
logs/

.DS_Store
```

And I did.

```
git rm --cached .
git add .
```

I expected that the files and directories in .gitignore would not be tracked but it did not work. Nothing in the files were ignored.

What can I fix this?

Your answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 places where you can configure ignoring files in git (and `.git/.gitignore` is not one of them). From highest to lowest precedence, they are:

- A `.gitignore` in the same directory as the path, or in any parent directory. `.gitignore`s are committed and versioned along with the rest of the project. There is commonly one in the root of the repository, but you can have as many as one per directory. This file should contain project specific things to ignore (build output and such).
- A per repository file called `.git/info/exclude`. This file is not versioned and will only impact that repository.
- A global file specified by the configuration variable `core.excludesfile`. It is typically placed in a users home directory named something like `~/.gitignore_global`, but could be named anything. This file is also not versioned. It applies to all git repositories. This file should contain project agnostic things to ignore (editor files, operating system files).

In your case, you should create a `.gitignore` in the root of your project with the following in it:

```
target/
logs/
```

And then create a global gitignore for the `.DS_Store` rule in `~/.gitignore_global`:

```
.DS_Store
```

Run `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global` to enable that file.

See [this helpful GitHub article](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) and [gitignore(5)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) for more information.